onFocus, onBlur not triggered in TouchableWithoutFeedback | react-native
The functions onFocus, onBlur of TouchableWithoutFeedback component aren't triggering. I wanted to make this work like the TextInput component, in terms of getting focused and unfocused, when the user clicks on this component and then on other components' on the UI.
Link: https://reactnative.dev/docs/touchablewithoutfeedback#onblur
<TouchableWithoutFeedback
      onFocus={() => {
        console.log('onFocus');
        setIsFocused(true);
      }}
      onBlur={() => {
        console.log('onBlur');
        setIsFocused(false);
      }}
    >
      <View style={styles.outerContainerStyle}>
          <Text style={styles.headerTextStyle}>{header}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.descriptionTextStyle}>{description}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.footerTextStyle}>{footer}</Text>
      </View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>

